# WPF: Bind to element in DataTemplate in ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, binding, datatemplate, resourcedictionary

I'd like to bind to a element's property (a ListBox's `SelectedItems.Count` in my specific case) that's dynamically inserted into my window from a `DataTemplate` located in a `ResourceDictionary`.  I'd like to enable/disable a button when the count reaches a certain number of `ListBoxItems` are selected. I thought this would work:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource myResourceKey}, Path=myListBox.SelectedItems.Count}" Value="25">
      <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'myListBox' property not found on 'object' ''DataTemplate' (HashCode=50217655)'. BindingExpression:Path=aoiListBox.SelectedItems.Count; DataItem='DataTemplate' (HashCode=50217655); target element is 'Button' (Name='myBtn'); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

How can I achieve this binding?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can write a workaround, but I strongly recomment not to implement it that way. Consider, that a style in a `ResourceDictionary` is an empty resource, which should be decoupled from any specific instance (in your case `myListBox`) in your application. Problem is, that you cannot use this *malformed* style on another `Button`. So you don't need to, better you shouldn't, declare it as resource.

I definitely recomment to declare this `Style` directly in the `Button`. E.g.

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" />
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myListBox, 
                             Path=SelectedItems.Count}" Value="25">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style> 
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Additionally, I would use a `Binding` via the `ElementName` property.